Connection Refused Error with H2O on WSL after Recent Windows Update
I'm experiencing a connection issue with H2O when running it on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) after a recent Windows update. Here's a detailed breakdown of the problem and the troubleshooting steps I've taken so far:
System Information:

Operating System: Windows with WSL (Linux kernel version
5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2)
WSL Distribution: Ubuntu 24.04
Java Version: Java 11.0.24
Python Version: Tested with Python 3.7, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, and 3.12
Anaconda Version: Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Linux-x86_64
H2O Versions: 3.42.0.2 up to 3.46.0.5

Problem Description:
When I start H2O on WSL using h2o.init() in Python, it attempts to form a cloud of size 2, including the node at 10.255.255.254:54321, but fails with a "Connection refused" error. This issue does not occur on a dedicated PC with Ubuntu OS.
Steps Taken:

Force Local Connection: Used h2o.init(ip="127.0.0.1", port=54321,
force_connect=True) to ensure H2O operates only locally. No success.

Network Configuration: Verified that no firewall settings are
blocking necessary ports. Temporarily disabled the firewall, but the
issue persisted.

WSL Configuration: Ensured WSL is up to date using wsl --update.
Restarted WSL and the machine, but the problem remains.

H2O Configuration: Checked for configurations that might instruct
H2O to connect to other nodes. Set H2O to use only the local IP
127.0.0.1.

Logs Analysis: Reviewed various H2O logs, all indicating the same
connection error with the node 10.255.255.254:54321.

Connection Test: Tested the connection using python3 -m http.server
54321 and was able to access the server from outside WSL without
issues.

Comparison with Ubuntu Laptop: On a laptop running native Ubuntu,
H2O functions correctly, suggesting the problem is specific to WSL.


Additional Information:
Until May 2024, H2O worked perfectly on my system. The only changes made since it last worked were keeping Windows and WSL updated. The issue was detected around 20/09/2024.
What might be causing this problem?

After further investigation, I've identified the root cause of the issue with running H2O in WSL. The problem arises specifically after updating from WSL version 2.1.5 to 2.2.1.
What I Found:
The H2O execution works perfectly in WSL version 2.1.5.
The issue appears immediately after updating to WSL version 2.2.1.
Changes in version 2.2.1, such as enabling DNS tunneling by default and other kernel updates, might be contributing factors.
Solution:
For now, the solution is to revert to WSL version 2.1.5, where H2O runs without any problems. Here are the steps I took to resolve the issue:
Uninstall WSL
Removed the current WSL version using PowerShell.
wsl --uninstall
Obs.: Although I haven't done it, I think it would be a good safety measure to make a backup of the Linux distro before uninstalling WSL.
Install WSL Version 2.1.5:
Downloaded and installed the WSL 2.1.5
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/2.1.5
This workaround allows me to use H2O effectively until a permanent fix is provided in future updates of WSL.
I hope this helps anyone facing similar issues. I opened an issue on the WSL GitHub, and I hope this problem is fixed in future WSL updates.
